# Program to automatically save “Who's viewed your profile” on LinkedIn without upgrading?

Tags: windows, social-networks

I'd like to keep track of the people who view my profile LinkedIn without having to upgrade my account. I am therefore looking for a program that would:

- automatically save “Who's viewed your profile” on LinkedIn without upgrading (name + date of visit)?
- works on Windows 7 (could be a web service or even a Google Chrome extension)
- free

---

Answers to comments:

- I was thinking of an app that would simply check every hour or so the “Who's viewed your profile” list and keep track of the visitors. It wouldn't be able to track people who visited my profile before I start using the app though (which indeed would be impossible to do unless exploiting some vulnerability in LinkedIn's system).
- A free account can show the last 5 visits:
  [image]

Comment: By "Who's viewed your profile" do you mean just the _number of_ people who have viewed your profile? (And perhaps the _number of_ times you have appeared in search results)?

Comment: I meant the full names (first+last) of everyone viewing my profile (put aside hidden names of course). Recording the number of times I have appeared in search results is a plus.

Comment: Sorry, yes you did state that in your question. But... this shouldn't be possible; should it? If an external app is able to do this then wouldn't it have to exploit some kind of vulnerability in LinkedIn's system?!

Comment: I was thinking of an app that would simply check every hour or so the  “Who's viewed your profile” list and keep track of the  visitors. It wouldn't be able to track people who visited my profile before I start using the app though (which indeed would be impossible to do unless exploiting some  vulnerability in LinkedIn's system).

Comment: Just to be clear: Is “Who's viewed your profile” visible even without an upgraded account? Does it show only 1 day worth of information or something similar? So the program would store this every day and show you the history?

Comment: I don't think it will come free unless linked allow that.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul A free account can show the last 5 visits.